# Partially Shifting to react from Django

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Basically I have a project in Django, in all it has 7 apps. I want to shift one of them in react.
Say app 'Student' is the one which I want in React. I want to know if its possible to do so, if yes then how?

Here is what I tried, I created a react project and using `npm run build` command I got a build of that react project.
Now for base URL of Student I rendered template which was in react build folder.
Something like this:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  ...
  path('student/', views.Student, name='student'),
  ....
]
```

**views.py**

```
def Student(request):
   return render(request, 'build/index.html')
```

Where `index.html` is the file present in build folder.

Using this approach I was able to render the react template but the other url routes were not working.
Please let me know what's wrong in this approach, if this approach is wrong then do suggest another approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do that. It has been explained extensively in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9o4GSkSo40&t=143s).